# Moving elements in clearcase to be "merge" able

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

Ours is a typical implementation of clearcase UCM :

I have 2 UCM projects each of which represent a release for us. proj2 being created from a stable baseline from proj1

proj1 and proj2 work in parallel and sometimes same elements in both get changed simultaneously. So files a.java lies in both projects and is being worked upon by developers at both. A weekly merge activity happens where downstream gets the latest from upstream project and merges are reconciled.This is my easy life.

As a part of restructuring code, team with proj2 has started moving elements (files mostly) to other places. When I say other places this could mean within the component or to a different component VOB. This has never happened before.

**The actual problem:**

When an inter-project merge happens, the destination branch version of element a.java could have been moved to a different location/folder. How do I ensure clearcase still merges it with the version coming from upstream project. Is using the `cleartool move` command enough for clearcase to know and merge at the right place ? For inter-VOB movements, will `cleartool relocate` command do the same for me. I am in a tightly controlled environment else would have created a sandbox and tested it myself.

I am banking @VonC or @Tamir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I say other places this could mean within the component or to a different component VOB

Note that with UCM, you cannot move elements to another component without **re-creating completely said element** (new history).

-For inter-vob component refactoring:

I would rather mirror the refactoring in proj1 (in a special Stream) and then attempt an inter-project merge from that stream, rather than hoping that a merge from an old directory structure to a new refactored directory structure goes well.

- For outer-vob component refactoring (new history)

A manual merge is safer in that case.

Comment: ok.. are we saying the move command (for within component) will work at least ?

Comment: @PulakAgrawal: yes, a "`cleartool move`" within a component works, but I would recommand making that move on both project before the inter-project deliver.

Comment: I understand the reason for your suggestion. But what really worked in our case is you do not make the move in the source project as a different team is working on that and they have "who and why move my cheese" syndrome. Apart from the fact they need to reconfigure the structure in their IDE (RAD unfortunately) doing which is a big ball of wax. So we did the move only in the destination and cc was good enough to merge it to the new location in the destination project seamlessly.

Comment: @PulakAgrawal sounds a good process for your situation. Interesting feedback.